# Connect Laravel 5.4 with Google cloud mysql locally

Tags: laravel-5, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect, Local Laravel application to GCP mysql instance. I am just trying to use mysql instance for local development and do not want to upload this on App Engine.

Steps follow: 
1. Added IP to Authorized networks in mysql instance 
2. updated .env file (refer below)
3. Able to connect to db instance with gcloud sql connect  -u=root and access database. 
4. Tried configuring config/database.php file 
5. Used instance IP for connection instead of localhost 
6. used DB_SOCKET : /cloudsql/:asia-northeast1:

.env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=<app-key>
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=<instance-ip>
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=<db-name>
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=*********
DB_SOCKET=/cloudsql/<project-id>:asia-northeast1:<db-name>


BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', <instance-ip>),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', <db-name>),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', *********),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/cloudsql/<project-id>:asia-northeast1:<db-name>'),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

I have another cakephp 2.0 project which runs locally with no problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what error you actually get it's a bit difficult to know *why* it doesn't connect. If you can post the actual error you're getting that may tell us why the connection fails.

That being said, you may want to connect using the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) instead. There's a [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-proxy-test) available that takes less than 5 minutes to set up the connection for local testing.

Answer (score 0):

While connecting from Compute Engine your don't need `DB_SOCKET`. I successfully connected using below `DB` creds inside laravel's `.env`.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=<Mysql instance IP from Google SQL mentioned under "Connect to this instance">
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD="db_user_pass"
```

[image]